# Error en lectura de registros - PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo este archivo que me permite insertar registros, cuando se inserte correctamente un registro necesito realizar una consulta para extraer el id de ese registro insertado, pero en la parte de realizar la lectura de registros mayores a 0 me marca el siguiente error: `Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in C:\Xampp\htdocs\Carta-Toscalia\reservar_back.php on line 27`

Logré detectar que si quito mi condicional "WHERE" de la consulta si ejecuta correctamente pero muestra todos los id, no solo el del registro que inserté.

Archivo:

```
<?php

include 'conexion.php';

//almacenar datos en variables
$nombre = $_POST["txt_nombre"];
$fecha = $_POST["txt_fecha"];
$hora = $_POST["txt_hora"];
$cantidad = $_POST["txt_personas"];
$folio = substr($nombre, 0,1).str_replace('-', '', $fecha).$cantidad;

//AGREGAR RESERVACIÓN
//insertar datos
$insertar = "INSERT INTO reservaciones(nombre, fecha, hora, personas,folio) VALUES ('$nombre','$fecha',
'$hora','$cantidad','$folio')";
//ejecutar consulta
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$insertar);

if(!$resultado){
    echo "<script> alert ('Error al Registrar');
    location.href = 'reservar.php';</script>";
}else{
    
    $folio="SELECT * FROM reservaciones WHERE nombre = $nombre AND fecha = $fecha AND hora=$hora AND cantidad=$cantidad;";
    $res = mysqli_query($conexion,$folio);

    if($res->num_rows>0){
        while($obtener=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            echo $obtener['id_res'];
        }
    }

    //echo "<script> alert ('Reservación Registrada');
    //location.href = 'index.php';</script>";

}

//cerrar conexion
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Comment: Esta consulta es errónea desde el punto de vista sintáctico, intenta corregirla así más o menos: **`$folio="SELECT * FROM reservaciones WHERE nombre = '$nombre' AND fecha = '$fecha' AND hora='$hora' AND cantidad=$cantidad";`** si observas, he rodeado casi todas las variables de comillas simples (`'`), debes rodear siempre de comillas simples todas la variables que sean de tipo cadena (varchar, text, ...). Dado que posiblemente `$cantidad` es de tipo `int` u otro tipo numérico, no le he puesto comillas simples, si fuera de un tipo cadena deberías ponerle comillas también.

Comment: @A.Cedano, aún con comillas simples me generaba el error, lo solucioné cambiando la forma de ejecutar la consulta, sin pasar directamente los valores.

Comment: Ok, es mucho más seguro hacerlo así. Hay menos riesgo de *Inyección SQL*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es por que mezclas métodos del estilo procedimental y del estilo orientado a objetos y tratas a `$res` como si de un objeto se tratara cuando no lo es.

Te vas a enterar que estructura de datos es en realidad si haces esto:

```
var_dump($res);
```

Como no es un objeto, por consiguiente no puedes recuperar ninguna propiedad y menos al valor asociado a alguna de estas

Lo primero que puedes hacer en la query es modificarla para que haga un conteo y en consecuencia te retorne el número de filas afectadas por la consulta así:

```
$folio="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reservaciones 
        WHERE nombre = $nombre 
        AND fecha = $fecha 
        AND hora=$hora AND cantidad=$cantidad;";
```

Posterior, pasarás de esto:

```
if($res->num_rows>0){
```

A esto:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($res)>0){
```

Recomendaciones:

- Si ya estás trabajando con *mysqli* entonces aprovechalo y usa [sentencias preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) pues no es recomendado estés pasando valores dinámicos de forma directa a la consulta
- Determina si usarás métodos del [estilo procedimental u orientado a objetos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) y sobre esa línea seguir